# How to upload a CSV file using AJAX with custom prefilter in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4.2 and currently I don't how to save a csv file into `public\csv\` directory using AJAX. I'm still finding some answers. Maybe someone can help me with this.

Here's my code:

In blade view:

```
 {{Form::open(['route' => 'file_upload', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'upload_form', 'method' => 'POST'])}}
    {{Form::file('csv_upload', ['id' => 'uploaded_file', 'accept' => 'text/csv'])}}
    {{Form::submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'id' => 'upload'])}}
 {{Form::close()}}
```

Javascript Ajax:

```
var ajax_ready = 1
var token = {{Session::get('_token')}}

if($.type(originalOptions.data) === 'string') {
              options.data = originalOptions.data+"&_token="+token;
 }else if($.type(originalOptions.data) === 'object') {
         //Here I got a new error
 }else{
     options.data = $.param(($.extend(originalOptions.data, {'_token':mmad_token})));
 }

 options.url = originalOptions.url.slice(0,originalOptions.url.indexOf("?_token="));

   if (ajax_ready!=1){
              jqXHR.abort();
   }
  ajax_ready = 0;
});
$('form#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var uploadFile =  $('#uploaded_file');

    var ext = $("input#uploaded_file").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    var file = $('input[name="csv_upload"]').val();

    if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) === -1) {
             alert("Please upload a .csv file!");
             return false;
    }

     var csv = uploadFile[0].files;
     var form = new FormData(this);

     var csvFile = {lastModifed: csv[0].lastModified, fileName: csv[0].name, size: csv[0].size, fileType: csv[0].type};

      $.post('{{ URL::route("file_upload") }}?_token={{Session::token()}}',{
           data: form
      }).done(function(response){

      });

});
```

PHP:

```
public function upload_csv()
{
    $inputs = Input::all();

    $csvFile = $inputs['data']['fileName'];

    $path = public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'csv'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $path2 = public_path('csv/');

    if(is_dir($path2))
    {
        @move_uploaded_file($csvFile, $path2.$csvFile); //This line can't move the uploaded files in my desired directory
    }

    return json_encode(['success' => 1, 'description' => 'Successfully Upload File']);

}
```

This code below does work when not using AJAX:

```
  if(Input::hasFile('csv_upload'))
    {
        $file = Input::file('csv_upload');

        $originalFilename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $rules = ['csv_upload' => 'required|file:csv'];

        $validate = Validator::make(['csv_upload' => $file], $rules);

        if($validate->fails())
        {
            return json_encode(['error' => 1, 'description' => 'File must be in .csv format']);
        }

        $path = public_path('/csv/');

        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path);
        }
     }
```

Console.log of csv

[image: CSV DATA]

Comment: dont you think you need to pass csrf token... afaik you need to pass

Comment: I'll update my question because I currently send the csrf token along with the url.

Comment: why dont you use plupload library, it can post a file to your url. It'll work with your existing controller.

Comment: The other code is working fine but with ajaxprefilter but when it is included I don't know to accept the custom requests.

Answer (score 5):

You can not move file because when you submit form with ajax **file is not being sent** with ajax,For sending file you have to send file with **FormData()** javascript Object.

If you check in `upload_csv` controller by putting `print_r($_FILES);` you will get empty array.

So use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) on client side for appending file, then try agian.
You aren't getting error beacuse you have used php **Error Control Operators** likes`@move_uploaded_file($csvFile, $path2.$csvFile);`.

if you need working example then tell me i will give it to you.

Code For Your Help:
1. In blade view:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $('form#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var uploadFile =  $('#uploaded_file');

        var ext = $("input#uploaded_file").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
        var file = $('input[name="mmad_csv_upload"]').val();

        if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) === -1) {
                 alert("Please upload a .csv file!");
                 return false;
        }
        var csv = uploadFile[0].files;
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        formData.append('uploaded_file', $("#uploaded_file")[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('lastModifed', csv[0].lastModified);
        formData.append('fileName', csv[0].name);
        console.log(formData);


        $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::route("file_upload") }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) { //alert(returndata); return false;

        }
        });      

    });
 </script>
```

2.Controller

```
public function file_upload(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = Input::all();
    $csvFile = $inputs['fileName'];


    $path = public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'csv'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $path2 = public_path('/csv/');
    if(is_dir($path2))
    {
        $success = $request->file('uploaded_file')->move($path2, $csvFile);
    }
    return json_encode(['success' => 1, 'description' => 'Successfully Upload File']);

}
```

Comment: Can you please give me? I want to fetch data files using `Input::file('filename')`

Comment: I have edited a my answer and added code.Please check.

Comment: Okay i'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: It say's `Error: Illegal invocation`.

Comment: Note. This is not Laravel 5.1, the version I'm using is 4.2

Comment: I know now why my laravel code didn't work it's because of `AJAX PREFILTER`

Comment: you have used a $.post() function of jQuery instead of you have to use $.ajax function for formdata() have you changed that one.
You are getting Illegal invocation because jQuery is trying to serialize the jQuery object for $.post, and it can't. It's probably trying to call a string method, and is passing it a jQuery object as context, thus causing the error.

Comment: I've just delete the `$.ajaxPrefilter`. It solves my problem but I want to have `$.ajaxPrefilter` so I tried to manipulate it to fully solved my problem. It's in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To move the uploaded file to a new location, you should use the move method. This method will move the file from its temporary upload location (as determined by your PHP configuration) to a more permanent destination of your choosing:

```
Input::file('fileName')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

If you need additional validations, you can check it at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files

Comment: Yes but I do that one. And still not works so I go for the native of uploading a file.

Comment: The request parameters is in ajax. The thing is if I do ajax the uploaded file didn't store into the temporary file.

Comment: Do you get file object in laravel? Check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22400560/1045444)

Comment: No I get an array of objects. It's in the image above

Comment: When I use `FormData()` then passed it in the through data of ajax. I get Illegal Invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Default AJAX POST does not support file uploads. Use jQuery Form to upload files successfully. Full documentation of file upload at http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Below my example of a recentlty build script... My Controller uploads the files to S3, but is easy to be implemented with local storage.

```
var progress = function(event, position, total, percent) {
    $(".progress-bar").width(percent + '%');
    $(".progress-bar").html(percent + '%');
    if(percent > 50) {
        $(".progress-bar").css('color','#fff');
    }
    if(percent == 100) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".progress").html('<span class="processing-msg">Processing... Please be patient!</span>');
            $(".processing-msg").fadeIn('slow');
        }, 1000);
    }
}

var success = function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    $("#"+obj.hidden, parent.document).val(obj.filename);
    var src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/spincms'+obj.path+'thumb_'+obj.filename;
    $("#uploaded-"+obj.hidden, parent.document).html('<img class="img-circle uploaded-img" src="' + src + '">');
    $(".progress").html('<span class="processing-msg-next">File has been uploaded and processed. Do not forget to submit the form!</span>');
}

var options = {
    target: '#output',
    uploadProgress: progress,
    success: success,
    resetForm: true
};

$(document).on('click', "#upload-now", function(e) {
    $(".progress").html('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>');
    if($("#upload-form input[type=file]")[0].files.length == 0) {
        $(".progress").html('<span class="processing-msg-next">No file selected!</span>');
        return false;
    } else {
        var name = $("#upload-form input[name='name']").val();
        var token = $("#upload-form input[name='_token']").val();
        var file_name = $("#upload-form input[type=file]")[0].files[0].name;
        $("#upload-form").ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the solution than @aldrin27? The whole idea for stackoverflow is to share the outcome and/or mark an answer as solution... Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use the  [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) as it will make things much more easier for you to work with for example , this is the jquery part that you will use :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#upload_form').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Your file has been uploaded, thanks"); 
    }); 
});
```

and in your controller you can code it like :

```
pubilc function postUpload()
{
    $success = false;
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('csv_upload'))
        {
            $file = Input::file('csv_upload');
            if(!File::isDirectory(storage_path('csv'))) {
                File::createDirectory(storage_path('csv'));
            }

            $file->move(storage_path('csv'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
            // now your file is on app/storage/csv folder
            $filePath = storage_path('csv/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $success = true;
        }   
    }


    return Response::json(['success'=>$success]);
}
```