# Cannot upload file using Laravel & AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8

I cannot upload files using Laravel & AJAX and failing to understand why, when i'm checking for $request->hasFile('file_name'), I'm getting null however I'm getting the file path when i am dd ing $request->file_name.
I'm attaching the required scripts.
Controler:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'contact_number' => 'required|numeric',
        'email' => 'required', 
        'total_exp' => 'required|numeric',
        'skillsets' => 'required',
        'current_organization' => '',
        'remarks' => '',
        'file_name' => 'required|max:2048'
    ],
    [   
        'name' => 'This field is mandatory',
        'contact_number' => 'This field is mandatory',
        'email' => 'This field is mandatory', 
        'total_exp' => 'This field is mandatory',
        'skillsets' => 'This field is mandatory',
        'total_exp.numeric' => 'Only numberic values allowed',
        'contact_number.numeric' => 'Only numberic values allowed'
    ]);

    try{
    $career = CareerForm::updateOrCreate([
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'contact_number'=>$request->contact_number,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'total_exp'=>$request->total_exp,
        'skillsets'=>$request->skillsets,
        'current_organization'=>$request->current_organization,
        'remarks'=>$request->remarks,
        'file_name' => $request->file_name,
        ]);
    }catch(Exception $e1){echo $e1;}
    /*$fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();
    $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);*/

    //$file = $request->file('file_name')->store('public/documents');
    dd($request->hasFile('file_name'));
    Storage::disk('local')->put($request->file($request->file)->getClientOriginalName(), 'Contents');
    return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "file" => $request->file,
    ]);
```

HTML code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h2>Career Form using AJAX</h2>
<form class="form-signin" id="form_todo"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Career Form</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('name')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Contact Number</label>
  <input name="contact_number" type="" id="c_n" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('contact_number')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" id="eml" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('email')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Total Experience</label>
  <input name="total_exp" type="" id="exp" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Experience" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('total_experience')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Skillsets</label>
  <input name="skillsets" type="text" id="skl" class="form-control" placeholder="Skillsets" required="" autofocus="">
  @error('skillsets')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Curent Organization</label>
  <input name="current_organization" type="text" id="c_o" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Organizations (Optional)" autofocus="">
  @error('current_organization')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror
  <label for="" class="sr-only">Remarks</label>
  <input name="remarks" type="text" id="rem" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks (Optional)" autofocus="">
  @error('remarks')
  <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
    {{$message}}
  </div>
  @enderror

  
  <input type="file" id="file_id" name="file_name" class="form-control">
  
  <button class="btn  btn-primary btn-block" id="career_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }

    });
  });
    $("#form_todo").on('submit',function(e) {
    //$("#career_btn").click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      let name = $('#inputName').val();
      let c_n = $('#c_n').val();
      let eml = $('#eml').val();
      let exp = $('#exp').val();
      let skl = $('#skl').val();
      let c_o = $('#c_o').val();
      let rem = $('#rem').val();
      let file_up = $('#file_id').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "career/store",
        data: {
          name:name,
          contact_number:c_n,
          email:eml,
          total_exp:exp,
          skillsets:skl,
          current_organization:c_o,
          remarks:rem,
          file_name:file_up,  
        },
        success: function(data) {
          
        }
      });
    });      
    </script>

@endsection
```

Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CareerForm extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='career_forms';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'contact_number', 'email', 'total_exp', 'skillsets', 'current_organization', 'remarks','file_name','file_path'];
}
```

Not uploading the route and the migrations cuz they are fine.
Any help will be appreciated.

Please look for the solution below, changing the AJAX code made it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }

    });
  });
    $("#form_todo").on('submit',function(e) {
    //$("#career_btn").click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "career/store",
        data: formData,
        datatype: 'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
        }
      });
    });
  
</script>
```

Comment: You have to submit a form using FormData() function, then you can get the file in request in your controller.
Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820805/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-laravel-5-3/41821076

Comment: Don't forget about the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @zoltalar multipart/form-data had been given in form tag only, seems like FormData() usage was necessary thanks ,Assad for suggesting and ,zoltalar thanks for trying out to help. I'll anyways upload the running code below.