# image upload in database and folder using ajax laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I am trying to upload the image to database and folder using ajax and laravel but i am getting the error like `call to a member function getclientoriginalextension on string` and when i dd the values in my controller image path only not coming.

my view :

```
<form role="form" name="campaignForm" id="campaignForm" action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <input type="text" name="project_name" autocomplete="off" id="project_name" placeholder="Company name" class="form-control">

    <input type="text" name="website_url" id="website_url" autocomplete="off" placeholder="http://www.yourdomain.com" class="form-control">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" class="form-control">

    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter the location you want to target" class="form-control">

    <input type="text" name="group" id="group" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Group (optional)" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-save" value="add"  class="btn actionBtn btn-primary">
</form>
```

my ajax :

```
$("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })

    e.preventDefault(); 

    var formData = {
        project_name: $('#project_name').val(),
        website_url: $('#website_url').val(),
        location: $('#location').val(),
        group: $('#group').val(),

        image : $('#image').val(),
    }


    $.ajax({

        type: type,
        url: my_url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

controller:

```
    public function campaign(Request $request){


    $task = new projects();

    $task->project_name = trim($request->project_name);
    $task->website_url = trim($request->website_url);
    $task->location = trim($request->location);
    $task->group = trim($request->group);


    $file = trim($request->image);

    if ($request->hasFile($file)) {
    $destinationPath = 'images'; // upload path
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
    $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    $task->image = $fileName; 
  }   

  dd($task);

}
```

any help would be appreciated .Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Laravel does not receive uploaded image. `$request->image` should be instance of `UploadedFile` class, but in your case it is just string like `"C:\fakepath\custom-image.jpg"`

Giving respect to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647320/4990125), try this:

```
$("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = document.forms.namedItem("campaignForm"); // high importance!, here you need change "yourformname" with the name of your form
    var formData = new FormData(form); // high importance!

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: my_url,
        dataType: "json", // or html if you want...
        contentType: false, // high importance!
        data: formData, // high importance!
        processData: false, // high importance!
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its worked for inserting Data .But when i am trying to edit the form , its storing as empty values . I don't understand why ?

Comment: i am glad it worked. do you mean editing existing instance? well in that case you may put `old('username')` in form fields, like this `<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">`. Here is [old input docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input)

Comment: I sorted out the issue .Now everything is working like charm .Thank you :)

Comment: i have one more problem here . if i use form data like this , i m not getting all the selected values from the drop down . Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: @HarshithaNaidu ok may be try to add value via `formData.append(name, value);` Here is [source docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: Even this was not working . Is there any alter solution for this ? or can i send two parameters in data form ?

Comment: i think yes you may try send two parameters in data form

Comment: Yeah sure let me try out even that